# Nodejs get 401 Unauthorized with secure route jwt

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, jwt, middleware

I made a back-end in js node and mysql to be able to login and access to secure routes with jwt.
Until now i'm able to login and i get a token. I created a route protected by a middleware (like the code below) but when i try to get this route i always get a 401 Unauthorized and error 'Your session is not valid'. I follow [this](https://webdeasy.de/en/complete-login-system-with-node-js-vue-js-restapi-jwt-part-1-2/#comment-279) tutorial step by step but doesn't work for me. The complete code is in the link for details.

Thanks in advance :)

```
module.exports = {
    isLoggedIn: (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            const decoded = jwt.verify(
                token,
                'SECRETKEY'
            );
            req.userData = decoded;
            next();
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(401).send({
                msg: 'Your session is not valid!'
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It might be useful to see what is in that `err` object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for your response. I get 'jwt is not defined'

Comment: What a waste of time... It's solved ! Next time, i'll log error ^^.
Thanks !

Comment: do you have `const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');`in your code?

Comment: Yes i just fix it with import jwt

Answer (score 0):

I see that you figure it out

my point is (or my problem) is with this line of code

```js
req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
```

that's wrong what's going to happen when I just sent you a token like

```js
tokennnnnnnnnnn
```

so my fix is something like that (usually it's going to be 'Bearer')

so why not something like that

```js
req.header.authorization.replace(/bearer/i, '')
```

something like that I think it's going to be nice! <3